# Drupal: Pass function name as page arguments

Tags: drupal, menu, module, hook

I have simple module:

```
function cabinet_menu() {
$items['cabinet'] = array(
    'title' => 'cabinet',
    'title callback' => 'cabinet_title',
    //'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page arguments' => array('cabinet_mysettings'),
    'page callback' => 'cabinet_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $items;
}
```

I want to pass to 'page arguments' a function called 'cabinet_mysettings'

```
function cabinet_mysettings() {
debug('call settings');
global $user;

$cabinet = user_load($user->uid);
return $cabinet;
}

function cabinet_page($cabinet) {
debug($cabinet);
}
```

In 'cabinet_page' debug shows only string "cabinet_mysettings".

Why does the menu hook not understand that the page arguments is not a function name but a sting?

UPD: devel module hook_menu:

```
  $items['devel/reinstall'] = array(
'title' => 'Reinstall modules',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('devel_reinstall'),
'description' => 'Run hook_uninstall() and then hook_install() for a given module.',
'access arguments' => array('access devel information'),
'file' => 'devel.pages.inc',
'menu_name' => 'devel',
```

);

I think that 'devel_reinstall' is a function.

Does anyone know how such callbacks work?

Answer (score 0):

Page arguments are not designed to do something behind the scenes. You use them to pass arguments to page callback by putting them in the url.

Putting string in page arguments as you did ('page arguments' => array('cabinet_mysettings')) causes that only that string is passed. There is no way around this. Refer to [hook_menu documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more comprehensive explanation.

Therefore, in your case I would consider something like this:

```
function cabinet_menu() {
  $items['cabinet/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'cabinet',
    'title callback' => 'cabinet_title',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'cabinet_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function cabinet_mysettings() {
  debug('call settings');
  global $user;

  $cabinet = user_load($user->uid);
  return $cabinet;
}

function cabinet_page($my_param_name) {
  $cabinet = cabinet_mysettings($my_param_name);
  debug($cabinet);
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: m1n0, it is clear to me. But I want to share the data my module generates in both 'cabinet_title' and 'cabinet_page' functions. There willbe no wildchar in URL. I want to have the function that is called before 'cabinet_title' and 'cabinet_page'. It has to generate the module data.

Comment: Should I call 'cabinet_mysettings' in every function or there is correct way?

Comment: Yes, calling 'cabinet_mysettings' in every function you need your data is possible solution...but also you can consider having a static object which stores that data...or even session variable...it really depends on what you your specific case is, but you shoudln't call that function multiple times in case if it does some extensive processing or if it loads data from database.
My favourite option is static object, it is quite elegant solution but its not completely "the drupal way"

Comment: "calling 'cabinet_mysettings' in every function" is neither 'the drupal way' nor 'any other good way'. Even if it stores static data. The best way is to have object with 'run()' method where all data is inside of it but it is not drupal at all :-) Thanks for your answers, m1n0.